# Generate an intuitive unique string based on an ordered pair of strings?

Tags: string, algorithm

Related: [Generate a unique string based on a pair of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102420/generate-a-unique-string-based-on-a-pair-of-strings)

I want to generate an *intuitive* unique string to denote an *ordered* pair of strings.

Clearly, `stringA + stringB` is very intuitive but not unique if you consider, for example, `"st"  + "ring" == "stri" + "ng" == "string"`.

Also, unlike the linked OP, I'd like to have `uniqueString(stringA, stringB) != uniqueString(stringB, stringA)`, i.e. noncommutative.
Something like `MD5(stringA) - MD5(stringB)` might work considering the linked OP, but I feel it's very unintuitive.

Any ideas?

Comment: `MD5(A)+MD5(A+B)` ?

Comment: stringA.length + stringA + stringB ? You could easily split it into the two strings again, and it works if one or both strings are empty.

Comment: @StanislavKralin That would work but not simple as I wish.

Comment: @m69 What happens if stringB.length === stringA.length ?

Comment: "xxx" + "yyy" = "0003xxxyyy".

Comment: @m69 I was stupid, but let me think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the length of the first string into the resulting string; that way, you know where the split is, and "xy" + "z" is different from "x" + "yz".
Zero-pad the length, so that it always has the same number of digits (depending on the maximum length of the strings).

Examples (with a maximum string length of 999):

```
"xxx" + "yyy" = "003xxxyyy"  
"xx" + "xyyy" = "002xxxyyy"
"xxxyyy" + "" = "006xxxyyy"  
"" + "xxxyyy" = "000xxxyyy"  
"" + ""       = "000"
```

Alternatively, if the maximum length of the string is unknown, you could use a delimiter after the length:

```
"xxx" + "yyy" = "3;xxxyyy"
```

You don't have to use a special character for this, or escape the delimiter in the strings, because there is no ambiguity:

```
"a;b" + ";c;" = "3;a;b;c;" = length + delimiter + "a;b;c;"
```

Answer (score 1):

If tasked with such a problem, I would try a CSV-like approach, e.g.

- `stringA` + `stringB` => `stringA;stringB`
- `stringA` + `string;B` => `stringA;"string;B"`
- `stringA` + `string"B` => `stringA;"string""B"`

Comment: Looks nice, but implementing this by yourself sounds super error prone.  Is there any reference implementation or a function like csvConcat in any language?

Comment: This seems a lot more complex and confusing than just using a single escape character, which you also escape, e.g `,` -> `\,` and `\ ` -> `\\ ` (as shown in dornadigital's answer).

Answer (score 0):

This feels very much like a serialization issue... Put two values in the same place and still be able to separate them afterwards.

One of the simplest ways is to have a delimiter à la csvs, though that would require you to implement a unique character or sequence of characters.

Removing this issue would be as simple as adding a '\' before all instances of that delimiter in your string along with all instances of '\'.

As an example:

```
"hello, " + "wor\d"
"hello\, " + "wor\\d" //Add in the escape characters
"hello\, ,wor\\d" //Second comma is not escaped, parser knows to split the string back into two components there
```